# Passing 'select from dual' as parameter to java callable statement

Tags: java, oracle, callable-statement

I am trying to pass `SELECT FROM DUAL` as parameter to callable statement in java as in example:

```
{?=call function1( ?, (select function2(?) from dual), ?)}
```

When I call this function I get exception: *ORA-06550: line 1, column 165: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null others...*

When I call function as `{?=call function1( ?, ?, ?)}`, it works fine, but I need to call another function as a parameter (password encryption for example).

Is there a way to call one function as parameter to another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
BEGIN function1( ?,function2(?), ?) END;
```

or

```
{?=call function1( ?, function2(?), ?)}
```

You don't need to call dual. Just in case, you can always use PL/SQL itself. Easy to to use and maintain.

[Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_jdbc.htm)

[Returning data from anonymous PL/SQL block](http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/10/returning-data-from-anonymous-plsql.html)  - contains some useful code snippets on PL/SQL usage in JDBC.

Comment: worked, never thought of that :) thank you very much